# EpiServer Find excerpt and XhtmlString search

Tags: asp.net, episerver

I've been on this for hours.

I have a page model with a bunch of properties. One of these is `MainBody` which is of type `XhtmlString`.

When I override the SearchText property and do a bunch of things to ensure the proper excerpt is returned, when I search for something contained in `MainBody` I get no results. As if EpiServer.Find doesn't search in that property (for some reason).

When I remove the `SearchText` override, I can find pages, but the excerpt is a compilation of random fields.

Any help at this point is much appreciated.

Comment: Exactly how do you override the properties?

Comment: By doing a bunch of checks to see if some of the properties of the page type are `null`, and trimming the string to be returned in the `SearchText`'s get method.

Comment: The actual code would help us a bit more, where is the code placed to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SearchText is one of the fields used when doing a [UnifiedSearch](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/EPiServer-Find/9/DotNET-Client-API/Searching/Unified-search/). So if you override that property and only return some info, then a lot of content will be missing in the actual search.

If you want you own excerpt, it would probably be better to add your own property for that.